# How to create dynamic width and static height for UICollectionView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing `UICollection` view with `customcell`. Here, I need to create dynamic width based on `customcell` label string and `static` `Height` need to set. Here, I used below code for `dynamic` `width` don’t know about static height. How to achieve this?

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return (items[indexPath.row] as String).size(withAttributes: nil)
        //return CGSize(width: label.frame.width, height: 33.5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the `collectionViewCell's` `width` based on the `text` that you want to add in the `label`.

Assuming that `items` is an `array` of `String`,

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let textWidth = items[indexPath.row].size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)]).width + 30.0 //30.0 is the extra padding
        let width = min(textWidth, 100.0) //100.0 is the max width
        return CGSize(width: width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Add the `attributes` and the `height` as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @PGDev. I am getting below error in console - Please check the values `returned by the delegate.
The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f9d0ae023d0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7f9d0b877400; frame = (20 342.5; 335 25); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000042f330>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000a217c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 25}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f9d0ae023d0>`

Comment: This is not the error description. These are the properties of collectionView printed. Error must be something else if there is any. What output are you getting anyways?

Comment: I have array of values. I am adding those values like a Tag chips with help of UICollectionView Horizontal flow @PGDev

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or is the UI distorted. Kindly clarify for further help.

Comment: one more doubt how to set max width? Because certain limitation need to set for dynamic width.

Comment: Updated that too. Check.